# Communicate between two Fragments without using Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have an issue like this:

I have 3 Fragment, Fragment_Main is navigation drawer with content is Fragment_Content and Drawer is Fragment_Drawer.

When I click an item in Fragment_Drawer, Fragment_Content will show beside and Fragment_Drawer will close. But onClick event happens in Fragment_Drawer, if I want to close Drawer, I need to do it in Fragment_Main.
I try to use Interface but it doesn't work because context is Fragment (not Activity).

Comment: USE Fragments.setArguments

Comment: check example http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-navigation-drawer-example-using-fragments/

Answer (score 0):

you can use activity's context in all fragments maintained by that activity.

```
getActivity()
```

it will return activity's context. use same context in all fragments.